# Antonym of anthropomorphic

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is there an antonym to anthropomorphic meaning "The attribution of characteristics and behavior of inanimate objects to that which is alive"? I found "[zoomorphism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zoomorphism)," but it doesn't have quite the definition I want.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: [Word for attributing animal-like mentality to humans](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/115614/8019).

Comment: Nitpick: the definition you give seems to actually be for anthropomorph**ism** rather than for anthropomorph**ic**. Are you more interested in a noun or an adjective?

Comment: Do inanimate objects have behaviors? Do you mean in phrases like "You lazy lump! Don't just sit there like a bump on a log."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anthropomorphism means treating an object as a person, perhaps an antonym might be **objectification**

> : to treat (someone) as an object ...
>   - *[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objectify)*

Comment: Or [***dehumanization***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dehumanize) *to treat (someone) as though he or she is not a human being*. That's also as defined by M-W, Unfortunately, the related derivative [***objectivism***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/objectivism) has a significantly different meaning, and I'm not convinced there even *are* derived ***-ic*** forms for either, or an ***-ism*** relating to ***dehumanization***.