# animals and society terms

Tags: terminology

I am doing a paper on native Americans totem animals and how the native Americans give animal characteristics to the human and was wondering what is the scientific word for this?

Comment: Are you asking for the scientific word for ***spirit animal***?

Comment: The scientific word for what? For "giving animal characteristics to a human being?" See if this answers your question: [Word for giving animal characteristics (esp. physical ones) to humans](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275874/word-for-giving-animal-characteristics-esp-physical-ones-to-humans?lq=1)

Comment: Please capitalize the word "Native" in the term "Native Americans"

Comment: "Native Americans" is a pretty broad brush. I doubt every indigenous people used totem animals in the same way.