# Is there an animal equivalent to "anthropomorphism"? That is: ascribing animal traits to non-animals

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm watching them demolish a building near me and thought that the JCBs were rather animalistic – almost dinosaur-like.

Anyway, it just got me onto thinking that it's not anthropomorphy if I want to give a non-human (animal) trait to an inanimate object.

Another example is that the comedian Isy Suttie once described an elderly person, hunched over and using a pair of walking sticks as resembling an insect (except she was funny). I suppose this is the same thing.

The only thing I can think of that might fit is "xenopomorphism".

Any ideas?

Comment: The full prefix is [anthropo-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anthropo-), so the "po" would likely not be part of the word.

Comment: The practice is known as _Totemism_, and it's pretty endemic. Check out advertising and children's stories, for two examples of many.

Comment: Related question: [Word for giving animal characteristics (esp. physical ones) to humans](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275874/word-for-giving-animal-characteristics-esp-physical-ones-to-humans)

Comment: Xenomorph is used in other contexts in pop culture ;)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(creature_in_Alien_franchise)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[zoomorphism](http://zoomorphism)

---

[zoomorphic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zoomorphic)

> 1 having the form of an animal
>
> 2 of, relating to, or being a deity conceived of in animal form or
>   with animal attributes

Comment: +1 for the correct answer and to save you from your rep of 666! ;)

Comment: Gah! It's so obvious! I'm kicking myself! Haha! Cheers!

Comment: @darthwomble The best answers always are. XD

Answer (score 3):

See **bestialize**, defined by [American heritage dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=bestialize)  as

> To represent or portray as an animal or beast.

Comment: I would use this when referring to describing a human as an animal (therefore slightly derogatory), but not for describing a machine.  So, this would perhaps fit the old-lady scenario in the original post (although that sounded more light-hearted than "bestialise" does to me).